# How do I make turtles circle around a point

Tags: rotation, netlogo

So my turtles have to circle around a point. My initial approach was to have them  rotate every tick perpendicular to the point they have to rotate around, and make them move forward. This however results in them gravitating to the same circle with a fixed radius. So how would one approach this problem?

Comment: that's because you are (I think) moving them all forward the same distance each time. You will have to do some trigonometry and work out how much to move them and in what heading.

Comment: http://www.educa.fmf.uni-lj.si/logo/doc/Apr.96/chpt6.pdf

Answer (score 1):

```
; move in a circle
; by
; Jose M Vidal

to setup
  clear-all
  create-n-turtles num-turtles
  reset-ticks
end

to create-n-turtles [n]
  crt n [
    fd random 20
    shake]
end

to update
  if (count turtles < num-turtles)[
    create-n-turtles num-turtles - count turtles]
  while [count turtles > num-turtles][
    ask one-of turtles [die]]
  ask turtles [move]
  tick
end

;
to move
  let cx 0
  let cy 0

  set cx mean [xcor] of turtles
  set cy mean [ycor] of turtles
  set heading towardsxy cx cy
  if (distancexy cx cy < radius) [
    set heading heading + 180]
  if (abs distancexy cx cy - radius > 1)[
    fd speed / 1.414]
  set heading towardsxy cx cy
  ifelse (clockwise) [
    set heading heading - 90]
  [
    set heading heading + 90]
  fd speed / 1.414
end

to shake
  set heading heading + (random 10) - 5
  set xcor xcor + random 10 - 5
  set ycor ycor + random 10 - 5
end
```